# Issues with naming empty dictionaries on Python

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-names

I was attempting to make an empty dictionary and use set default to allow duplicates. For some reason, the only variable name that would work is “d1”. Is there a reason why? I had another friend with way more experience in Python programming tell me to change it to d1, but I don’t know why.

I tried newdict and even d2 as a placeholder name. Neither would show as variables even after being assigned to an empty dictionary.

Comment: You can use any name you want for your variables. Please show your code that's not working, along with the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Can you add your code where you are initializing the dictionaries?

Comment: Have you tried asking your friend?

Comment: I did ask my friend, but he didn’t really offer an explanation!  I’m new to coding so maybe it was common sense for him?

Comment: I don’t have current access to my code, but I was combining a list of keys and values (some keys assigned to multiple values) using set default code. I kept an empty list for my new dictionary d1 = {} and later did d1.setdefault

Comment: I would share my code but I’m not sure how academic integrity stuff works for coding :(

Comment: @azhauri I don't think we can reproduce the issue without *some* of your code, and if we can't reproduce it, it's that much harder to help...can you share enough for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at least?

Comment: d1 = {}
    if len(keys) == len(vals):
        for vals, keys in zip(range(len(keys)), keys):
            d1.setdefault(keys, []).append(vals)
            print(d1)

Comment: That’s the code^^. I couldn’t change the name d1 at all and have it be recognized!